# Change style for element when dropdown is selected with conditions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm creating a dropdown from a JavaScript array. I want to show a span when some options are selected.

For example, I want to show the span when options "a" and "c" are selected, but not "b".

```js
var city = ["a","b","c"];

// Add array to city dropdown
var select_city = document.getElementById("city");

for(var i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
    let opt = city[i];
    let el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select_city.appendChild(el);
};

// Display output
var output = document.getElementById("output");

select_city.onchange = function() {
    output.style.display = (this.value == city.value && this.value == !"b") ? "block":"none";
};
```

```css
#output {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="-">- Choose city -</option>
</select>

<span id="output"></span>
```

Why is this not working? How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comparison logic is a bit broken:

```
this.value == city.value && this.value == !"b"
```

There is no `city.value` because `city` is *an array*.  You can check if that array *includes* `this.value`:

```
city.includes(this.value)
```

Additionally, `!"b"` doesn't make much sense.  To check if something is *not equal* to a value, use the `!=` (or `!==`) operator:

```
this.value != "b"
```

The result is:

```
city.includes(this.value) && this.value != "b"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I understand it now, and it's working great on my end :)